# Unit Test Case of redirection after successful Login of auth login view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-unittest

I have used Django auth login view and mentioned `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/team/'` in my `settings.py`. Now i want to write the unit test case if user successfully login then it should redirect to /team/.

My Login Url is:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'accounts/login.html'), name="login"),
```

My Test Case is :

```
class TestTeamsListView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):    
        obj1 = User.objects.create(username='test',email= 'abc@gmail.com', first_name='t', last_name='u', password="password")    
        self.login_url = reverse('accounts:login')


    def test_on_successful_login(self):    
        client = Client()    
        response = client.post(self.login_url,{'username':'test','password':'password'},format='text/html')    
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

When i run test then i am getting this result:

> AssertionError: 200 != 302

Answer (score 2):

You created a user with a password that is *not* hashed, as a result the login *fails*, and it returns the form with errors. You should create the user with [**`.create_user(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user):

```
obj1 = User.objects.create_user(
    username='test',
    email='abc@gmail.com',
    first_name='t',
    last_name='u',
    password='password'
)
```